# Network interface information on AIX

Tags: aix, network-interface

I want to get all the information about the network interfaces available on the AIX. Like on linux, we can get it from `/sys/class/net` files. Is there any files on AIX where I can find relevant information?

I am also trying to access it using "/dev/kmem" file. Which structure should I use to capture the information of network interface like in case of system information we use struct sysinfo. I am trying to get information for "ifnet" symbol. Can I get information like MTU, hardware address of the network interface from here?

Answer (score 2):

On AIX, stuff like this is held in the ODM, but the easiest way to get to it, is to use operating system commands.  For network interfaces,

`ifconfig -a` for logical information.  `lscfg`, `lsdev` and `lsattr` for physical details (or pseudo-physical in some cases).

Examples,

```
$ifconfig -a
en1: flags=5e080863,c0<UP,BROADCAST,NOTRAILERS,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST,GROUPRT,64BIT,CHECKSUM_OFFLOAD(INACTIVE),PSEG,LARGESEND,CHAIN>
        inet 192.168.1.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
en0: flags=5e080822,c0<BROADCAST,NOTRAILERS,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST,GROUPRT,64BIT,CHECKSUM_OFFLOAD(ACTIVE),PSEG,LARGESEND,CHAIN>
en2: flags=4e080822,80<BROADCAST,NOTRAILERS,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST,GROUPRT,64BIT,PSEG,CHAIN>
en3: flags=4e080822,80<BROADCAST,NOTRAILERS,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST,GROUPRT,64BIT,PSEG,CHAIN>
lo0: flags=e08084b<UP,BROADCAST,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST,GROUPRT,64BIT>
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 broadcast 127.255.255.255
        inet6 ::1/0
         tcp_sendspace 131072 tcp_recvspace 131072 rfc1323 1

$lsdev -Cl en1
en1 Available 10-78 Standard Ethernet Network Interface

$lscfg -vl ent1
  ent1             P1-I5/E1  10/100 Mbps Ethernet PCI Adapter II (1410ff01)

      10/100 Mbps Ethernet PCI Adapter II:
        Part Number.................09P5023
        FRU Number..................09P5023
        EC Level....................H10971A
        Manufacture ID..............YL1021
        Network Address.............0002556AF7A9
        ROM Level.(alterable).......SCU001
        Product Specific.(Z0).......A5204205
        Hardware Location Code......P1-I5/E1

$lsattr -El ent1
alt_addr        0x000000000000  Alternate Ethernet Address                    True
busintr         14              Bus interrupt level                           False
busmem          0xc0284000      Bus memory address                            False
chksum_offload  yes             Enable hardware transmit and receive checksum True
intr_priority   3               Interrupt priority                            False
ipsec_offload   no              IPsec Offload                                 True
large_send      yes             Enable TCP Large Send Offload                 True
media_speed     100_Full_Duplex Media Speed                                   True
poll_link       no              Enable Link Polling                           True
poll_link_timer 500             Time interval for Link Polling                True
rom_mem         0xc0200000      ROM memory address                            False
rx_hog          1000            RX Descriptors per RX Interrupt               True
rxbuf_pool_sz   1024            Receive Buffer Pool Size                      True
rxdesc_que_sz   512             RX Descriptor Queue Size                      True
slih_hog        10              Interrupt Events per Interrupt                True
tx_preload      1520            TX Preload Value                              True
tx_que_sz       8192            Software TX Queue Size                        True
txdesc_que_sz   512             TX Descriptor Queue Size                      True
use_alt_addr    no              Enable Alternate Ethernet Address             True
```

It seems you want to do this via an API.  The [ODM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Data_Manager) is the best bet then.  I have no idea how up-to-date this is, but here's the [IBM ODM API documentation link](http://publib16.boulder.ibm.com/doc_link/en_US/a_doc_lib/aixprggd/genprogc/odm.htm).

The ODM files are generally in `/etc/objrepos`, although a lot of files are symlinks to `/usr/lib/objrepos`.  Some products can install ODM files in other locations as well, for example, HACMP (now PowerHA System Mirror or something).

Comment: I want to access this information through C language, is there any API for it?

Comment: Probably, but I don't do development on AIX.

Comment: thanks for suggesting ODM, but I want to read it from any file or available API, is this network information is stored in files anywhere on AIX?

Comment: The ODM is a set of files.  The API gives access to those files.  So they both meet your needs.  'The ODM files are generally in /etc/objrepos'` as in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

ODM is how a user wants a system to be configured.  It is read at boot time and by mkdev, cfgmgr, etc.  But AIX allows direct manipulation of the attributes very much like a BSD system does.  e.g. you can change the IP address of an interface with `ifconfig en0 10.10.10.10` just like you would on BSD.  The ODM does *not* change in that case.  Or, you can do it with `chdev -l en0 -a netaddr=10.10.10.10` which updates ODM and the current setting.  Or, you can add a -P flag to the chdev and update only ODM so it takes affect upon reboot.

The ODM interfaces are documented in the standard IBM pubs http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.base/kc_welcome_61.htm.  All the various ways to access the current settings like ifconfig or netstat does are also documented.  A copy of the Stephens books or other BSD reference material can start you towards accessing the current settings.  I believe there are samples on AIX that demonstrate how to muck about with ODM.

Answer (score 0):

Simply `ifconfig -a` command will give you the answer.

Also you can try `smitty tcpip` for further analysis and configuration changes.